# Create magento product that links to an external website

Tags: magento, url

I want to add a product that is not held on my magento website. It must only show on my website. But when a customer clicks on a product it directly goes to the website that holds the product.

I want to give the URL to the product on the site. I am not sure how to do this. Please help me. Thanks.

Here are some screen shots that show what I actually want to do:

[product show on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/057a3.png)

[Customer goes to other website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwMm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way i would suggest you is to create an attribute called `external_url`, a textinput field. Assign it to required attribute sets then, while adding product if that particular product will be linked to external; input that field with external url.

And while populating product in listings, check if that external_url attribute value exists or not. (for eg on `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` check for this value `$_product->getData('external_url')`)

If the value exists then, change the product link(on product `list.phtml` change `$_product->getProductUrl()` with our `$_product->getData('external_url')`)